# Why boolean types do not contain yes/no?

Tags: language-agnostic, boolean

I know my question sounds stupid but I'm curious why almost all programming languages I know uses true/false or 1/0 for boolean types.

Yes/no is meaningful than 1/0 and is shorter than true/false. Is there any logical reason why true/false is preferred?

Note that I'm not trying to convince everybody that yes/no is more appropriate, I am just curious why.

Comment: Because they are more related to the notion of "truth". Note that Objective-C uses `YES` and `NO`, however.

Comment: I was actually hoping that the answer has historical value.

Comment: Programming languages just borrowed true/false from mathematics (boolean algebra) and philosophy (logic) works. [This post on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/43036/2218) links to Wittgenstein as the most probable inventor/popularizer of truth tables and, thus, true/false values in logic.

Comment: And, of course, list of valid values for boolean type heavily depends on a specific programming language/framework. Some implementations may support yes, no, maybe and [other values](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

"Yes" and "no" are ambiguous. Different languages treat them differently, especially when used multiply such as a double negative. The other options lack this ambiguity.